# 3ds max / maxscript - submitting dialog

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

Please guys I would like to automatically submit dialog,
but I am totally new in 3ds max...

please could someone help me what command line does it?
it is **"rollout name"...**
and submit button is called
**button btn_convertStart "Convert" width:60 align:#right across:2 offset:[150, 0]**

if anyone knows, thank so much for any further help

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should be something like this code:

on btn_convertStart pressed do
(
...
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).